# OpenLayers OverviewMap control?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I want to change  the overview map position to left side of the collapse listener.I am getting the map like as below image.I need map in black box.

[image]

```
const overviewMapControl = new OverviewMap({
  // see in overviewmap-custom.html to see the custom CSS used
  className: 'ol-overviewmap ol-custom-overviewmap',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM({
        'url':
          'https://{a-c}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' +
          '?apikey=Your API key from https://www.thunderforest.com/docs/apikeys/ here',
      }),
    }),
  ],
  collapseLabel: '\u00BB',
  label: '\u00AB',
  collapsed: false,
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse listener"? If that's another control, please post relevant code.

Comment: inside red circle button.I want map position to left side of that.

Comment: So you want that button outside overview map, on the right side of it? Picture would help.

Comment: No I want to change the position of the map.I want that map left side of the button .

Comment: Picture please!

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap-custom.html

Comment: @Mike ,I tried this but not working.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/overviewmap-forked-bcgrt

Comment: this one also not working @Mike.I don't know why css is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the control as shown in this example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap-custom.html), then you can just change the CSS to alter the absolute positioning of the overview box (from right to left). The second bit of CSS moves the collapse button within the overview.

```
.map .ol-custom-overviewmap, .map .ol-custom-overviewmap.ol-uncollapsible {
    bottom: auto;
    left: 0; //changed from auto
    right: auto; //changed from 0
    top: 0;
}
.map .ol-custom-overviewmap:not(.ol-collapsed) button {
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto; //changed from 1px
    left: 1px; //changed from auto
    top: 1px;
}
```